# Hibernate: Sorting a list without 'touching' the database

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got a many-to-many relationship in my database and I'm using Hibernate to retrieve a single row from the left hand side of the relationship.  I then just call the getter method to retrieve the associated right hand side of the relationship (lazy fetch).

As part of my work, I need to sort the right hand side "list" object by doing this:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

When I'm done my work, I'm currently calling:

```
session.getTransaction().commitTransaction();
```

Even though I haven't actually changed anything in the database in terms of the data, I can see in the logs that some INSERT statements were triggered.

What should I be doing in this situation so that I could order the list without incurring a database hit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are few ways to do it.

**First**, you can use `@OrderBy` annotation on your collection definition. Refer to [the link](http://java.dzone.com/news/sorting-collections-hibernate) here. In this way, Hibernate will append the query with `order by` clause.

**Second**, if you are using `Criteria` API to query the DB, you can use `addOrder()` method to add the `order by` clause.

**Third**, you can directly use `order by` clause in your HQL.

**Fourth**, you can do it in your code, using [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You can do it even after closing the session/transaction. In this case, you don't need an active transaction; but this could mean sorting partial data, because most of the time we don't fetch complete thing -- for performance reasons. In your case, it seems something has changed in the midst. However, try sorting it after closing the transaction.